# How do I configure Next.js to import data URL's from SCSS files?

Tags: sass, next.js, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to configure Next.js to work with foundation-sites by Zurb.

The foundation SCSS includes data URL's for some of the background images. An example is below:

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24"><polygon points="0,0 32,0 16,24" style="fill: #{$rgb}"></polygon></svg>');
```

When Next.js compiles the SCSS, it tries to add a file path to the data URL creating the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './foundation/util/data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24"><polygon points="0,0 32,0 16,24" style="fill: rgb(138, 138, 138)"></polygon></svg>'
```

Is there a way to configure Next.js so that it will use the data URLs as background images when compiling SASS files?

Comment: Update your Next.js version to 12.0.4-canary.1 or above. This was fixed in [PR#31134](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/31134).

Comment: That worked. Thanks.